# Custom highlight with ScintillaNET

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, syntax-highlighting, scintilla

in my winforms application I would create a custom syntax highlight, so I made this xml:

```
<ScintillaNET>
  <Language Name="default">
    <Styles>
      <Style Name="Default" FontName="Consolas"/>
    </Styles>
  </Language>

  <Language Name="customSql">
    <Lexer LineCommentPrefix="--" StreamCommentPrefix="/* " StreamCommentSuffix=" /*" LexerName="customSql" >
      <Keywords List="0">
        Data Source Initial Catalog User Id Password Database Server Trusted_Connection
        Integrated Security Network Library User Instance AttachDbFilename Failover Partner
        Asynchronous Processing Uid Pwd Provider SSPI
      </Keywords>
    </Lexer>

    <Styles>
      <Sytle Name="CHARACTER" ForeColor="Black"/>
      <Sytle Name="NUMBER" ForeColor="Red" />
    </Styles>
  </Language>
</ScintillaNET>
```

Looks fine for me. In my application I set the language and further properties as:

```
myC.ConfigurationManager.Language = "customSql";
myC.ConfigurationManager.CustomLocation = Global.Path + @"Resources\ScintillaNET.xml";
myC.ConfigurationManager.Configure();
```

I cannot figure why this still doesn't work. I have no exception, simply the text remain black. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps because you set the ForeColor to Black, but never set the BackColor to something other than black?

Comment: Hi, I've also remove that node but nothing happens. I could try to recompile ScintillaNET including my custom xml but I also think that should be an easier way